# Flink 1.8, parallelism > 1, source never outputs values

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a cluster with:

- 1 TaskManager
- 1 StandaloneJob / JobManager
- Config: `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1`

If I set `default.parallelism: 4` on a job with the Flink [PubSub](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/6594) source, I keep getting this error when starting my "job cluster"/taskmanager:

> [analytics-job-cluster-7bd4586ccb-s5hmp job] 2019-05-01 16:22:30,888 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Checkpoint triggering task Source: Custom Source -> Process -> Timestamps/Watermarks -> app_events (1/4) of job 00000000000000000000000000000000 is not in state RUNNING but SCHEDULED instead. Aborting checkpoint.

However, if I point the same job at a bunch of files, it works perfectly. What does this mean?

Comment: Hey, can You provide a little more logs ? Also, what is the exact configuration of Your cluster ? How many taskmanagers/job managers/ task slots do You have ?

Comment: @DominikWosiński I've updated the question with some more config I have. I was under the impression that you only needed one slot for one taskmanager and you could let parallelisable items (such as `(:Stream).keyBy`) parallelise themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue is that You need the `numberOfTaskSlots` equal to Your parallelism basically. So in this case If You have only 1 TaskManager with only 1 TaskSlot Flink will not be able to start the job properly as there is simply not enough slots for it. If You set the `numberOfTaskSlots` for the given TaskManager equal to the parallelism, then it should work well.

Comment: Does this mean that locally, the taskmanager spawns as many slots as you have parallelism?

Comment: Yeah, AFAIK it will create the number of slots to match the parallelism.